# Get videos which doesn't have any of given cateogires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to get all videos with those parameters. But even tho I don't get any error I still get some videos which have category [17] for example.

- Doesn't have any of fallowing categories `[15,17,26,32,35,36,37]`
- have duration longer then `100`
- They are unique

**Video.rb**

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_key = "id"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end
```

**My Query**

```
    @excluded_categories = [15,17,26,32,35,36,37]

    @videos = Video.joins(:categories).where("duration >= 100").where.not( categories: { id: @excluded_categories } ).pluck(:video_id).uniq
```

Is there better way how to write how write this query?

Comment: If you run the query in `rails console` for example, what does it show as the SQL it runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common SQL case: "fetch a list of object which don't have a certain relation".

The only solution in these cases is to transform the sentence in "fetch the list of objects which are not in the list of objects with a certain relation".

In you case you have to extract all the videos whch are not included in the list of videos with one of these categories.

In SQL:

```
select videos.*
from videos
where videos.id not in ( select v2.id
                         from videos v2
                         join categories_videos cv on cv.video_id == v2.id
                         join categories c on cv.category_id == c.id
                         where c.id in '15,17,26,32,35,36,37' )
```

Converted into ActiveRecord you will have:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  scope with_categories: ->(ids) { joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: ids}) }

  scope without_categories: ->(ids) { where.not(id: with_categories(ids) }
end
```

so in the end...

```
@excluded_categories = [15,17,26,32,35,36,37]
@videos = Video.without_categories(@excluded_categories)
```

P.S.

Your example has an issue since doesn't retrieve videos which don't have any category.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't mind that it featches vids without category, I don't want that.

Comment: Also you have there syntax error in your answer. the `with_categories` scope is missing `}` at the end. Otherwise thank you for your help.